# is "Donate this voicemail" redundant with ""Allow automated Google systems to analyze your voicemail messages"?

Tags: google-voice

If I "Allow automated Google systems to analyze your voicemail messages to help improve transcription quality":

[image]

Does it serve any proposed to check the "Donate this voicemail" option when editing a transcript?

[image]

I am surprised that the option is not checked by default when "Allow automated Google systems to analyze your voicemail messages to help improve transcription quality" is on, which makes me wonder whether there is any difference between those two options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have selected "Allow automated Google systems to analyze your voicemail messages to help improve transcription quality" then Google will run it through a machine that will attempt to transcribe it for you. With no human interaction.

If you edit or correct a voicemail transcript, the "Donate this voicemail" is then [listened to by an actual human](https://support.google.com/voice/answer/115986?hl=en) and they will transcribe it as they listen to it.

> If your voicemail was transcribed incorrectly or there was no transcription at all, you may want to send it because the voicemails will be listened to, manually transcribed and used to improve our transcribing service. They will only be used for this purpose.

That's the difference.

Comment: Let's get some (Google) glass!